# Spotlight isn't working whereas hemisphere Light and Point Light is working in my code

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

this is the code which I used for my 3d portfolio website using JavaScript Mastery Youtube video:

```
import React from "react";
import { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");
  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={1} position={[0, 1, 0]} groundColor="black" />
      <spotLight
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <primitive
        object={computer.scene}
        scale={0.75}
        position={[0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

In The Above Code the hemisphere Light and Point Light are working absolutely fine but the spotlight is Not reflecting on the object which is "computer.scene".

I Placed the object at a certain position and adjusted the lights with the proper configuration to show the results but hemisphere light is not working to its full extent as in the youtube video and spotlight isn't working at all.

Comment: Wow I am also watching the same video and I am getting an error of Unknown property 'intensity' found.

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing the same tutorial and got this same issue! Not sure if something changed since then or we messed up a step along the way, but the issue is with the intensity and distance of the spotlight, not that it's not working.

Keeping the same ratios, you can change the position to [-2, 5, 1] and raise the intensity to something in the triple digits. Then you should see the light!

```
<spotLight 
  position={[-3, 5, 1]}
  angle={1}
  penumbra={1}
  intensity={300}
  castShadow
  shadow-mapSize={1024}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue while following a tutorial, and I found a solution that might help others facing similar problems.

In the spotlight component, the position attribute {[-1, 3, 1]} specifies the position of the spotlight within the 3D scene. It's an array comprising three values [x, y, z], representing the coordinates of the spotlight relative to the scene's coordinate system.

```
    <spotLight
        position={[-1, 3, 1]}
        angle={2}
        intensity={400}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved my time after hours of messing with the coords